# Can someone help me get my audio to play in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm somewhat new to C#, and I just started with Unity a couple of days ago. I'm trying to set up a script, where as the racecar drives, you hear the engine, but if the racecar stopped, you don't hear the engine. However, I've been having trouble getting the audio to stop playing when the car stops moving. Here is the program:

```
using UnityEngine;


public class RaceCarMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    // Use this for initialization    

    float drivespeed = 0.3f;
    private AudioSource CarEngine;

    private void Awake()
    {
        CarEngine = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKey("up") == true || Input.GetKey("down") == true || Input.GetKey("left") == true || Input.GetKey("right") == true)
        {
            Drive();
            CarEngine.Play();
        }

        else
        {
            if (CarEngine.isPlaying)
            {
                CarEngine.Stop();
            }
        }


    }
    public void Drive()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("up") == true)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + drivespeed, transform.position.y);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("down") == true)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x - drivespeed, transform.position.y);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("left") == true)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + drivespeed);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("right") == true)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - drivespeed);
        }
    } 
}
```

I don't understand how the else statement didn't work, as Update() is supposed to update every frame. Does anyone have any suggestions/explanations?

Comment: First: Any physics related stuff should be started from the FixedUpdate function, because otherwise your graphics card changes how fast your car is. Your problem is probably fixed by removing those `== true`s in the upper if statement. Furthermore you should consider removing those `== true`s everywhere because it is considered as bad code style and is not good readable.

Comment: @TobiasBrohl Yeah that's true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a condition before playing music to check if it's already playing or not. like....

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("up") == true || Input.GetKey("down") == true || Input.GetKey("left") == true || Input.GetKey("right") == true)
    {
        Drive();
        if (!CarEngine.isPlaying)
            CarEngine.Play();
    }
    else
    {
        if (CarEngine.isPlaying)
        {
            Debug.Log("Stop playing....");
            CarEngine.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I see that there are some unnecessary lines of code, we are going to eliminate them.

Then, we create a method to reproduce the sound with a boolean parameter that will serve to reproduce or stop the audio, this parameter will be a boolean, then only the audio will be repudiated when that boolean is true, so you must say that it is true while press a key.

Else if you simplify the work, in fact you are verifying which of all is met from above the first if down to the last else, and the first line if fulfilled is executed, otherwise the else is executed.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RaceCarMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    float drivespeed = 0.3f;
    private AudioSource CarEngine;

    private void Awake()
    {
        CarEngine = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    void Start () 
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("up"))
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + drivespeed, transform.position.y);
            PlayCarSound(true);
        }

        else if (Input.GetKey("down"))
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x - drivespeed, transform.position.y);
            PlayCarSound(true);
        }

        else if (Input.GetKey("left"))
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + drivespeed);
            PlayCarSound(true);
        }

        else if (Input.GetKey("right"))
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - drivespeed);
            PlayCarSound(true);
        }

        else
        {
            PlayCarSound(false);
        }
    }

    private void PlayCarSound(bool play)
    {
        if(play /*&& !CarEngine.isPlaying*/) CarEngine.Play();
        else CarEngine.Stop();
    }
}
```